# base_url in js file

Tags: javascript, drupal, base-url

how we can print base_url in js file (in drupal)?please

Answer (score 26):

### Drupal 7

```
Drupal.settings.basePath
```

### Drupal 8

```
drupalSettings.path.baseUrl
```

Comment: For me the drupalSettings.path.baseUrl prints "/" and not the actual base url (e.g. http://example.dev) of the website. Do I miss any extra steps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$base_path`. See en example on [The Drupal JavaScript API](https://www.drupal.org/node/304258) under the "Drupal.settings" section.

Comment: This would be usefull only if you are dealing with both PHP and Javascript (define your setting in a custom PHP module, load it in Javascript, than access it). For any other custom setting, this is worth it. But for the base path, I think yoavmatchulsky answer is best.